# FFMPEG Slow time PLUS Watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

My command for slowing video time works:

```
ffmpeg -i c0028.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=2.5*PTS" output.mp4
```

But I can't find the right way to input a `logo.png` without it giving me an error:

```
-i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10"
```

Can anyone help me string these together in one command?

Comment: Update: I've been using this string: ffmpeg -i logo.png -i c0028.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setpts=2.5*PTS[v]; [1][v]overlay=10:10" output.mp4                and it will run and add the overlay, however there is no change to the speed of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input the video into setpts, not the image:

```
ffmpeg -i logo.png -i c0028.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]setpts=2.5*PTS[v];[v][0]overlay=10:10" output.mp4
```